# Performance of NSCoreData entries fetching

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, core-data

For example, i have 10 000 entries in database, and i need to display them into a UITableView.

So, i should setup all the NSCoreData stuff, create NSFetchRequest, and NSFetchedResultsController.

Then i could access these entries in cellForRowAtIndexPath with [NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndex] method.

**The questions is:**

1. Will NSFetchedResultsController load all these objects in a LAZY way, only after user actually SCROLL UITableView to a corresponding cells?
2. Is it enough just to set NSFetchRequest's fetchBatchSize to a number equal to cell count on screen?
3. Should i use separate NSManagedObjectContext with background thread for loading these objects? In case of separate thread, how will work [NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndex] method, while it called from Main-UI-thread?
4. Should i even worry about these things, while i have just 10k entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSFetchedResultsController` takes care of all your concerns for you.

1. **Lazy Loading?** Indeed, the FRC will try to be as lazy as possible. Nothing for you to do. Actually, it is optimized for scrolling, speed, performance, memory usage, you name it.
2. **Batch Size?** Irrelevant. You can just forget about it. If you feel like it, set up a performance test and compare with and without `batchSize`. I predict you will not find any difference or it will be negligible. (If anything at all maybe with extreme scrolling speeds.)
3. **Separate `NSManagedObjectContext`?** Absolutely no. The `NSFetchedResultsController` is supposed to be used on the main thread.
4. **Concern with number of records?** You do not have to worry about this at all for the above reasons, especially lazy loading. I have had great results with X00.000s records.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set the batch size correctly.
2. I go for about twice as much
3. Don't bother, just run it off the main UI moc
4. Try it and see.  CD can handle that volume, but there are still performance optimisations that you can do tha depends on things that aren't in your question.